# How to push tags in ADO repo via yaml pipeline without PAT

Tags: azure-devops, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to tag a commit with a version number in a pipeline:

```
        - script: |
            git config --global user.email "pipeline@example.com"
            git config --global user.name "pipeline"
            git tag -a v$(GitVersion.semVer) -m "Alpha" 
            git push origin v$(GitVersion.semVer)
```

I've granted the build service contribute, read, and create tag perms but it fails with

> 

fatal: Cannot prompt because terminal prompts have been disabled.
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://acme@dev.azure.com/org/proj/_git/repo': terminal prompts disabled

> 

Am I correct in my assumption that the build service can't authenticate with the repo?  It works if I replace origin with a PAT, but I'd prefer not to use a PAT (rotation requirements, listed as me, etc.).  My next step was to auth using a [managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops), which I'm successfully using to publish the web app to Azure but unsure how to get the token to present in lieu of the PAT.

I am hopeful I am missing something basic to push a tag to a repo hosted in ADO (same org).

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems:
#1 I was waaaay overthinking it; it is simple to access repos:
Answer courtesy @Levi Lu-MSFT: [Execute git push within Azure DevOps pipeline but getting fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65263161/execute-git-push-within-azure-devops-pipeline-but-getting-fatal-error?rq=2)
Revised code:

```
        - script: |
            git tag -a v$(GitVersion.semVer) -m "Alpha" 
            git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/org/project/_git/repo v$(GitVersion.semVer)
```

#2 I had the org build service assigned with the correct perms. It turns out I also needed the Project Collection Build Service with Contributor writes.
Answer courtesy Copilot:
Look at pipeline error, grab user guid referenced, search for user in project settings->repositories->repo->security, add Contributor.